# What we're learning now *is/are* gerunds

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Which auxiliary is to be used? Maybe both can be?
My research: I have already asked lots of questions like this one, but none of those have been able to make this specific question clear to me.

1. What we're learning now *are* gerunds
2. What we're learning now *is* gerunds

Answer (score 1):

How would you rephrase the clause "what we're learning now"?

> The subject is gerunds.

> Today's topic is gerunds.

> This lesson is about gerunds.

However you reframe it, it refers to one thing. Thus *is*.